# Best approach for converting int into array

Tags: c, embedded

I have following variables in my code

```
uint8_t array[8];
uint64_t epoch;
```

I need to copy the epoch variable into array(msb of epoch should go into array[0]).
I did this logic by copying each and every byte individually

```
array[0] = epoch>>56;
array[1] = epoch>>48;
.
.
array[7] = epoch;
```

What's the other alternative??

Comment: Is your code actually correct?

Comment: ... and a union won't work if this is little-endian system. If you want portable, just write a function.

Comment: I have used memcpy. It's copying lsb of epoch into array[0]

Comment: @Lundin: OK, got you. I will delete my related comments then...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should be endian-independent:

```
const size_t SIZE64 = sizeof(uint64_t);

for(size_t i=0; i<SIZE64; i++)
{
  uint8_t bits = 8 * (SIZE64-i-1); // 8 bits * (8 bytes - byte index)
  array[i] = epoch >> bits;
}
```

Comment: I wonder if the compiler doesn't already optimise the call to `sizeof(uint64_t)`?

Comment: @Gio Of course it does, it is a compile-time constant. I merely created a const variable for readability (which will also get optimized). The line `uint8_t bits = 8 * (sizeof(uint64_t)-i-1);` is a bit hard to read in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
for (int i=0, shift=56; i<8; i++, shift-=8)
    array[i] = epoch >> shift;
```

This basically does:

```
array[0] = epoch>>56; // first iteration (shift = 56)
array[1] = epoch>>48;
..
..
array[7] = epoch>>0; // last iteration (shift = 56 - 7 * 8 = 0)
```

Note that the `>>` operator always shifts the bits towards the least significant digit, hence the endinannes of the architecture doesn't matter for this piece of code.

Answer (score -2):

I think this is more efficient because it shifts a fixed number of bits:

```
uint8_t i=8;
uint64_t e=epoch;
while(i){
    array[--i]=e;
    e>>=8;
}
```

Comment: Eternal loop since uint8_t cannot be less than zero. Classic bug.

Comment: Yeah if you are lucky you'll get a seg fault when accessing array[255]. Otherwise the program will simply go bananas. Since the OP tagged this as embedded system, bananas is the most likely outcome.

Comment: @Gio It can be less than 0, which is the main bug.

Comment: I think it works because the loop is executed until i reaches 0, i never is negative. When i reaches 1: while(1){array[i=0]=e;e>>=8;}, then while(0) is false and loop finishes.

Comment: The OP wants the MSB of epoch to go into array[0], you're doing exactly the opposite. array[0] will contain the LSB after this operation.

Comment: array[0] will contain MSB because 'e' is shifted right 7 times before array[0]=e.

Comment: I have run my code and it works fine, no eternel loop, no seg fault, no bananas, array[0] contains MSB... Please check my code, your comments and your votes.